# How to update the two Edittext parralley using Textwatcher in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, keylistener, textwatcher

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_datepicker);


        final EditText text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        final EditText text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text2);


        text1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                try {
                    int total = Integer.parseInt(s.toString()) + 1;
                    text2.setText(String.valueOf(total));
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });

        text2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                try {
                    int total = Integer.parseInt(s.toString()) + 2;
                    text1.setText(String.valueOf(total));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });


    }


    }
```

Hi I am facing one problem with multiple edit text updating parallel.If i enter value in first edit-text, the second edit text changed.Same in second edittext. But the key listener of cursor in edit-text has problem. i am unable to get the cursor.How to solve this problem?

Comment: You mean the cursor is not updating

Comment: yes.You are correct.I got stackoverflow error.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get what you are doing (or trying to do).
In the `onTextChanged` for `text1` you are triggering the `onTextChanged` for `text2`. Seems like infinite text change listeners being triggered here.
The logic for what is happening ->
Suppose the user types in the character `1` into `text1`. `total` is now `2`. Now you set `text2` as `total` which is `2`. This in turn triggers the Text Change Listener for `text2`. Now `total` is `2`+2=`4`. You now set `4` as the text for `text1`. This in turn triggers the Text Change Listener for `text1`.
Seems like a never ending infinite loop to me. This is the reason you are getting a `StackOverflow`Error (lol) What did you actually want to do?

Not really sure about what might solve that problem (I don't have a working copy of Android Studio at hand), but moving the block to `afterTextChanged` might do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way. TextWatcher will update the values to second EditText through Handler through the method afterTextChanged.

```
 EditText text1;
 StringBuffer previousChar=new StringBuffer();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        text1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        if(!previousChar.toString().equals(s.toString())){
                            Message msg=new Message();
                            msg.obj=s.toString();
                            localHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                            previousChar=new StringBuffer(s.toString());
                            Log.i("TAG", "TextEntered = "+s);
                        }
                    }
                });}
```

The handler will be used to update the text in second EditText

```
private Handler localHandler = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            String value=(String)msg.obj;
            text2.setText(value);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 includeTW = new TextWatcher(){

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                      int count) {
                if(!(includedText.getText().toString().equals("")))
                {
                    excludedText.removeTextChangedListener(excludeTW);
                    String included = includedText.getText().toString();
                    excludedText.setText(included); //////// Error Line
                    excludedText.addTextChangedListener(excludeTW);
                }

            }



        };


        excludeTW = new TextWatcher(){

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(!(excludedText.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
                    includedText.removeTextChangedListener(includeTW);
                    String excluded = excludedText.getText().toString();
                    includedText.setText(excluded);
                    includedText.addTextChangedListener(includeTW);
                }

            }



        };
        includedText.addTextChangedListener(includeTW) ;
        excludedText.addTextChangedListener(excludeTW);
```

This will give the solution exactly what i want.I am getting the value with the cursor moving in each edittext.

Answer (score 0):

Remove TextChangeListener of another EditText when first one is in effective mode and add that after text change..

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_datepicker);


        final EditText text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        final EditText text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text2);


        text1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    **text2.addTextChangedListener(null);**
                try {
                    int total = Integer.parseInt(s.toString()) + 1;
                    text2.setText(String.valueOf(total));
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    **text2.addTextChangedListener(this);**
            }
        });

        text2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
{
                    text1.addTextChangedListener(null);
                try {
                    int total = Integer.parseInt(s.toString()) + 2;
                    text1.setText(String.valueOf(total));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
{
                **text1.addTextChangedListener(this);**

            }
        });


    }


    }
```